# Some strange work in login.jsp Spring Security and Spring Boot

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have got the web application with login and logout pages built with the help of Spring Security but my `login.jsp` works in some strange way. Actually I don't have any exceptions in my console and I can't tell what is going on strange but I see it works wrong.

I put the wrong parameters into `login.jsp` deliberately, it is refreshed only without `?error=true` query parameter. Then I put correct login/password into `login.jsp` and it is refreshed with parameter `?error=true`, but should redirect me to `contacts.jsp`. Then I put correct login/password again and it redirects me to `contacts.jsp` as I wanted. I mean it goes 3 phases if I put wrong parameters instead 2 (refresh with "error param ---> `contacts.jsp`").

My code:

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class RootController extends AbstractUserController implements ErrorController {

    private static final String PATH = "/error";

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String root() {
        return "redirect:/contacts";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/contacts", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String contactList() {
        return "contacts";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
    public String login(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) boolean error){
        model.addAttribute("error", error);
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/logout_sec", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public String logoutPage (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth != null){
            new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
        }
        return "logout_sec";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String register(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("userDTO", new UserDTO());
        model.addAttribute("register", true);
        return "register";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = PATH)
    public String error(){
        return "redirect:/login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveRegister(@Valid UserDTO userDTO, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status, ModelMap model) {
        if (!result.hasErrors()) {
            try {
                super.create(UserUtil.createNewUserFromDTO(userDTO));
                status.setComplete();
                return "redirect:login?message=app.registered";
            } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {
                result.rejectValue("Login", "---");
            }
        }
        model.addAttribute("register", true);
        return "contacts";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return PATH;
    }
}
```

Security configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
                .antMatchers("/js/**", "/css/**").permitAll()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureForwardUrl("/login?error=true")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/contacts")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout_sec")
                .permitAll();

    }
}
```

Login page:

```
<html>
    <jsp:include page="headTag.jsp"/>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <%--<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check" var="loginUrl"/>--%>
                    <c:url value="/j_spring_security_check" var="loginUrl"/>
                    <form:form class="navbar-form" role="form" action="${loginUrl}"
                         method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="username"> Login: </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Login" class="form-control" name='username' id="username">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password"> Password: </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" name='password' id="password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
                        </div>
                    </form:form>
                    <br/>
                    <form class="navbar-form" action="<c:url value="register.jsp" />">
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-primary" role="button">Register</button>
                    </form>
                </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <c:if test="${not empty error}">
            <div class="error">${error}</div>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${not empty logout}">
            <div class="message">${logout}</div>
        </c:if>

        <p>
            <br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <p>User login: <b> Bill </b></p>
        <p>User password: <b> 112233 </b></p>

        <p>Стек технологий: <a href="http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/">Spring Security</a>,
            <a href="http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html">Spring MVC</a>,
            <a href="http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/">Spring Data JPA</a>,
            <a href="http://spring.io/blog/2014/05/07/preview-spring-security-test-method-security">Spring Security
                Test</a>,
            <a href="http://hibernate.org/orm/">Hibernate ORM</a>,
            <a href="http://hibernate.org/validator/">Hibernate Validator</a>,
            <a href="http://www.slf4j.org/">SLF4J</a>,
            <a href="https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson">Json Jackson</a>,
            <a href="http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSP">JSP</a>,
            <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages_Standard_Tag_Library">JSTL</a>,
            <a href="http://tomcat.apache.org/">Apache Tomcat</a>,
            <a href="http://www.webjars.org/">WebJars</a>,
            <a href="http://datatables.net/">DataTables plugin</a>,
            <a href="http://ehcache.org">Ehcache</a>,
            <a href="http://www.postgresql.org/">PostgreSQL</a>,
            <a href="http://junit.org/">JUnit</a>,
            <a href="http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/">Hamcrest</a>,
            <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>,
            <a href="http://ned.im/noty/">jQuery notification</a>,
            <a href="http://getbootstrap.com/">Bootstrap</a>.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<jsp:include page="footer.jsp"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I guess I made Spring Security configuration file wrong.

Comment: The order of your `antMatchers` is important. The first match fires, all others will not be applied. So only `.antMatchers("/**").access("IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY")` will be applied.

Comment: Yes, bro. I changed the order in `antMatchers` and it works in 2 phases, but when I put wrong data into login.jsp I am redirected to `localhost:8080/j_spring_security_check`. That means I dont get `login?error=true page`. Thanks for help BDW.

Comment: You restricted your login page to `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")` that seems wrong.

Comment: I have deleted this annotation but still have the same result.